# Neo4j Access to record went out of bounds of the page. Migration Neo4j 5.5.0 to 5.10.0

Tags: neo4j, cypher, database-migration, neo4j-apoc

I'm attempting to upgrade from `Neo4j 5.5.0` to Neo4j `5.10.0`, but currently my tests on this version are failing with the following error:

```
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.DatabaseException: Access to record Node[79841,used=false,created=false,rel=-1,prop=-1,labels=Inline(0x0:[]),light,fixedRefs=false] went out of bounds of the page. The record size is 15 bytes, and the access was at offset 1875 bytes into page 146, and the pages have a capacity of 8192 bytes. The mapped store file in question is /data/databases/neo4j/neostore.nodestore.db
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.Futures.blockingGet(Futures.java:110) ~[neo4j-java-driver-5.11.0.jar:5.11.0-ea56edc8c126b032c4a7dd8c4c571ec35419ca44]
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalResult.blockingGet(InternalResult.java:111) ~[neo4j-java-driver-5.11.0.jar:5.11.0-ea56edc8c126b032c4a7dd8c4c571ec35419ca44]
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalResult.list(InternalResult.java:87) ~[neo4j-java-driver-5.11.0.jar:5.11.0-ea56edc8c126b032c4a7dd8c4c571ec35419ca44]
at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.response.RestModelResponse.<init>(RestModelResponse.java:49) ~[neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-4.0.6.jar:4.0.6]
at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest.execute(BoltRequest.java:169) ~[neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-4.0.6.jar:4.0.6]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.lambda$query$0(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:147) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-4.0.6.jar:4.0.6]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.doInTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:600) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-4.0.6.jar:4.0.6]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.doInTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:574) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-4.0.6.jar:4.0.6]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.query(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:145) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-4.0.6.jar:4.0.6]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.query(Neo4jSession.java:445) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-4.0.6.jar:4.0.6]
```

What may be wrong and how to fix/configure it? On `Neo4j 5.5.0` everything is working fine.

**UPDATED**

Found another issue - I'm using the Neo4j Docker image with the docker-maven-plugin:

```
<image>
    <name>neo4j:${neo4j.version}</name>
    <alias>neo4j</alias>
    <run>
        <ports>
            <port>${neo4j.http.port}:7474</port>
            <port>${neo4j.bolt.port}:7687</port>
        </ports>
        <volumes>
            <bind>
                <volume>
                    ${project.basedir}/../docs/graphaware/plugins/${neo4j.version}:/plugins
                </volume>
            </bind>
        </volumes>
        <env>
            <NEO4J_AUTH>${neo4j.username}/${neo4j.password}</NEO4J_AUTH>
            <NEO4J_db_memory_transaction_total_max>0</NEO4J_db_memory_transaction_total_max>
            <NEO4J_server_memory_pagecache_size>2G</NEO4J_server_memory_pagecache_size>
            <NEO4J_server_memory_heap_initial__size>5G</NEO4J_server_memory_heap_initial__size>
            <NEO4J_server_memory_heap_max__size>5G</NEO4J_server_memory_heap_max__size>

            <NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted>apoc.*</NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted>
        </env>
        <wait>
            <http>
                <url>http://${docker.host.address}:${neo4j.http.port}/browser</url>
            </http>
            <time>1200000</time>
        </wait>
    </run>
</image>
```

When I use Neo4j version `5.5.0`, the following query works fine:

```
MATCH  ( childD:Vacancy )  
WITH collect({`childD`: childD}) as childDDgRdgd  
CALL apoc.cypher.mapParallel2(" 
WITH _.childD as childD WHERE  (childD.`active` = $active0)  AND  (childD.`status` = $status1)  
WITH childD 
RETURN childD  ", {`status1`:'APPROVED', `active0`:true}, childDDgRdgd, 6, 10) 
YIELD value as value   
WITH value.childD as childD   
return childD
```

However, when I switch the Neo4j version to `5.10.0` for the Docker plugin, the query fails with the following exception:

```
Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.cypher.mapParallel2`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error polling, timeout of 10 seconds reached.
```

I also added it to the plugins directory:

```
apoc-5.10.0-extended.jar
apoc-5.10.1-core.jar
```

What am I doing wrong?